# Can one buy an Ethernet and HDMI Thunderbolt adapter?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, hdmi, ethernet

I need both of them and I am wondering if it is possible to buy them together or if I have to get two separate items?

Also I am seeing a lot of third party Thunderbolt>HDMI adapters for cheap and then no generic Ethernet adapters, only the stock (expensive) Apple ones. Is there a way to get an off brand Ethernet adapter?

Comment: Other than a Thunderbolt Dock, e.g. [OWC Thunderbolt 2 Dock](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/Thunderbolt/Dock/OWC/Thunderbolt2-Dock/), I've not seen a Thunderbolt Adapter having only Thunderbolt to Ethernet and HDMI combined. Obviously the cost of two separate Thunderbolt adapters will be considerably less then a Thunderbolt Dock.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - there are quite a few docks to connect one cable to a Mac and have gigabit ethernet as well as HDMI out (and some even support 4K resolution on the HDMI).

- Elgato https://www.elgato.com/en/thunderbolt-2-dock
- Belkin http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F4U085/
- Sonnet http://www.sonnettech.com/product/echo15thunderboltdock.html
- OWC https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/Thunderbolt/Dock/OWC/Thunderbolt2-Dock/

I've linked to the top of the line thunderbolt 2 versions of the docks. If you don't need the fastest speed look for older models of 10 Gbps thunderbolt as refurb/used or still new stock which are discounted in price from the faster 20 Gbps models.

It's far cheaper to buy two single use adapters, though - the electronics are smaller and less complicated than needed for a full dock that takes one cable and splits into multiple functions.

Comment: Also - p.s. I'm not aware of any docks/adapters that only do ethernet + HDMI since they aren't marketed in the US - but I doubt you would have problems finding one in a market in Shenzhen (or have one custom made) for about the price of the consumer adapters from Apple. You'd be without warranty or a company to back the item as well as need to get there in the first place, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get them separately. Have you thought about using an ethernet to usb adapter? Those are cheap. Then again, the ethernet to thunderbolt from Apple isn't bad ($30). USB 2.0 may have (although it would be unlikely) a speed bottleneck. Ignoring this, there are many generic adapters for ethernet to USB. I'd make the choice based on which port you would rather have unused rather than price. The difference will probably be at most $20.